# Can't assign object returned by service to $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

I'm trying to assign data returned by service to $scope property. Somehow it doesn't work properly. The service method correctly get data via $http.get but then it is not assigned to $scope in the controller.

```
app.service('StoreService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    this.getStoreNamesService = function () {
        console.log('getStoreNames called');
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/storys')
            .success(function (response, status) {
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            })
    };
}]);

app.controller('ItemFormController', ['$scope', '$http', '$mdDialog', 'itemService', 'StoreService', function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog, itemService, StoreService) {

    $scope.storeNames = StoreService.getStoreNamesService();
}]);
```

Printing the response in service gives correct data. But when I'm printing $scope.storeNames it gives me undefined also on the views there is no data.

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute'])
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('teal')
        .accentPalette('red')
        .warnPalette('red');
});

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/addItem', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/addItemForm.html',
            controller: 'ItemFormController'
        })
        .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/first.html'
        })
        .when('/store', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/itemsInStore.html',
            controller: 'StoreController'
        })
        .when('/item/:itemId', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/itemView.html',
            controller: 'ItemController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            template: '<h1>otherwise template</h1>'
        })
});
```

The order of script tags:

```
    <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
<script src="js/angular-1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="js/AngularMaterial/angular-material.js"></script>

<!-- Your application bootstrap  -->


<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/service/itemService.js"></script>
<script src="js/service/StoreService.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/testController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/SideNavController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/ItemFormController.js"></script>

<script src="js/controller/sampleController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/ItemController.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is happening because AJAX call is not completed and your function returns befote that. Either send a callback with $scope as a parameter or even better use Promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
app.service('StoreService', ['$http', function ($http) {

this.getStoreNamesService = function () {
    console.log('getStoreNames called');
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/storys').then(
        function success(response, status) {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        })
    };
}]);

app.controller('ItemFormController', ['$scope', '$http', '$mdDialog', 'itemService', 'StoreService', function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog, itemService, StoreService) {
    StoreService.getStoreNamesService().then(function(result){
        $scope.storeNames = result;
    });
}]);
```

You can only assign the variable `storeNames` after the promise is resolved. The way you were doing, the promise was being assigned to the variable.

Also notice that `.success()` is deprecated. Use `.then()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you were mistaken

1. You should return the promise object return by $http method from service method `getStoreNames`.
2. You should not be passing `$scope`(context) to service to modify it.
3. You should use `.then` function to get value from promise object.

   ```
   app.service('StoreService', ['$http', function ($http) {
     this.getStoreNamesService = function () {
       //return promise here
       return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/storys');
     };
   }]);
   ```

**Controller**

```
StoreService.getStoreNamesService($scope).then(function(response){
   $scope.storeNames = response.data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Angular you're better off returning a promise, the $http service returns a promise and you can move the success callback to the scope:

```
app.service('StoreService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.getStoreNamesService = function () {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/storys');
    };
}]);

app.controller('ItemFormController', ['$scope', '$http', '$mdDialog', 'itemService', 'StoreService', function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog, itemService, StoreService) {
    StoreService.getStoreNamesService().then(function (response, status) {
        $scope.storeNames = response.data;
    });
}]);
```

Or you can create a deferred object which is similar in that a promise is returned, except it just returns the data and not the $http status codes, etc:

```
app.service('StoreService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    this.getStoreNamesService = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/storys').then(function(response, status){
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        });
        return deferred;
    };
}]);

app.controller('ItemFormController', ['$scope', '$http', '$mdDialog', 'itemService', 'StoreService', function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog, itemService, StoreService) {
    StoreService.getStoreNamesService().then(function (data) {
        $scope.storeNames = data;
    });
}]);
```

See [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

In both cases the scope object should be populated within the controller.